# Large Toolbar causes odd scrolling behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I have a `Toolbar` that contains more content than the typical Toolbar (which normally just has a title). My Toolbar has an image and some text, and the full height of the Toolbar ends up being around `250dp`.

However, because the Toolbar header is so large, it leaves little space on the screen for scrolling. Below the Toolbar I have a `RecyclerView` where I show the main content. Only the `RecyclerView` portion of the screen seems to be scrollable.

When I scroll up or down (while the Toolbar is on the screen or just about to be on the screen), it causes some weird scrolling behavior because of the Toolbar's size. The scrolling will sometimes halt and requires me to scroll in smaller increments (or swipe over the entire screen).

How can I get around this odd scrolling behavior? Is there a better way to implement a large Toolbar like the one I have (`250dp`)?

Here is my current `Activity`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayout"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is `toolbar.xml` (the Toolbar itself):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/green">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_image"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hey!"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet the scrolling is not working because you don't actually *have* a toolbar.  Your `CoordinatorLayout` really has nothing to coordinate with.

Your toolbar.xml should probably have a `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout` wrapping a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Have a look at the layouts in [chrisbanes cheesesquare Material Design demo on Github](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)